# Creating a floating widget for Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, widget

I am looking to create a simple and very lightweight widget for Windows 7. 
I was thinking about something that looks like the little floating circle of Messenger for iOS or Android. 
The widget's function would be to perform various action (one per widget or many per widget, I'm still not sure about this) when clicked: open up a program, set something, shut down the pc etc. 
Is it possible to create something like this using Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swing or JavaFX to do that. You can for example [change the shape of a Swing window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html), which by default is a rectangle.

The JavaFx showcase can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) (Ensemble). The example you are looking for, can be found here: "Samples -> ScreenGraph -> Stage -> Advanced Stage".

Example:

[image]